# Visit pages in for loop and scroll to bottom of each before proceeding to the next

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm using Puppeteer to automate some web surfing. So given a list of words, I want do a Google search with that word, randomly select a search result, open the result's page and scroll to the bottom. Then do the same for the next word.

What I've got so far:

```
'use strict';

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless: false,
            args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']
        });

        let pages = await browser.pages();
        const page = pages[0];

        var words = ['Aardvark', 'Apple'];
        for (let index = 0; index < words.length; ++index) {

            await page.goto('https://google.com');
            await page.click('[name=q]');
            await page.keyboard.type(`What is ${words[index]}`);
            await page.keyboard.press('Enter');
            await page.waitForSelector('h3.LC20lb', { timeout: 10000 });
            await page.evaluate(() => {
                let elements = document.querySelectorAll('h3.LC20lb');                
                let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * elements.length) + 1;
                elements[randomIndex].click();
            }).then(() => {
                    page.once('load', () => {
                    autoScroll(page);
                    page.waitFor(3000);
                });
            });

        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
})();

async function autoScroll(page) {
    await page.evaluate(async () => {
        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var totalHeight = 0;
            var distance = 400;
            var timer = setInterval(() => {
                var scrollHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
                window.scrollBy(0, distance);
                totalHeight += distance;

                if (totalHeight >= scrollHeight) {
                    clearInterval(timer);
                    resolve();
                }
            }, 100);
        });
    });
}
```

This does the navigation fine but does not select a random search result for the first word, only for the second. So in this scenario the steps are as follows:
 1. Open Google
 2. Search for "What is Aardvark"
 3. Press enter
 4. Open Google
 5. Search for "What is Apple"
 6. Press enter
 7. Select random search result
 8. Wait for page to load
 9. Scroll to bottom

How can I make the steps below work?
 1. Open Google
 2. Search for "What is Aardvark"
 3. Press enter
 7. Select random search result
 8. Wait for page to load
 9. Scroll to bottom
 4. Open Google
 5. Search for "What is Apple"
 6. Press enter
 7. Select random search result
 8. Wait for page to load
 9. Scroll to bottom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems as `then()` does not return a promise, it is resolved with an `undefined` value not waiting for its content functions. Also, it seems you have an off-by-one error in the random index calculation (the code can return `elements.length` number which is too much).

Try this:

```js
        for (let index = 0; index < words.length; ++index) {

            await page.goto('https://google.com');
            await page.click('[name=q]');
            await page.keyboard.type(`What is ${words[index]}`);
            await page.keyboard.press('Enter');
            await page.waitForSelector('h3.LC20lb', { timeout: 10000 });

            await Promise.all([
              page.evaluate(() => {
                  let elements = document.querySelectorAll('h3.LC20lb');
                  let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * elements.length);
                  elements[randomIndex].click();
              }),
              page.waitForNavigation(),
            ]);
            await autoScroll(page);
            await page.waitFor(3000);

        }
```

Comment: Working! I added `page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0', timeout: 30000 }),` since some pages take forever to load everything and I don't really care to wait that long. Thanks alot